# Deploying backend server for android in-app purchases for classytaxi?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, npm, in-app-subscription

I am struggling for days to implement android user subscription into android. I am using the google dev tutorial for Java in-app purchases:

https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiJava

At the last section, I need to deploy backend Server as described here:

https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiServer

What I did:

1. cloned the server files and folders [in the tutorial](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiServer) into my PC
2. Opened CMD and directed to the folder
3. logged into firebase by `firebase login` --> OK
4. added the firebase project by `firebase use -add` --> OK
5. initiated a function command `firebase functions:config:set app.package_name="com.mypackage.app"` --> OK
6. `deploy firebase` --> **ERROR**

Error is as below:

```
=== Deploying to 'api-2341234***'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\vafa\Firebase\server\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vafa\Firebase\server\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vafa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-18T22_21_16_430Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294963238
```

I noticed after deploying, a "server" folder is made inside the project folder that nothing is inside the server folder. I tried putting the package.json file inside it and deploy again, but it did not work.

*** It was also mentioned in git as issue [here](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/288) and someone responded:

> Notes: In firebase.json,
>   https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/master/ClassyTaxiServer/firebase.json
>   There are no 'server' or 'web' directory, firebase cann't deploy
>   functions and hosting with these folder.

My firebase project folder:
[image]

My server folder:
[image]

My src folder:
[image]

Error after changing the folder structure:

```
Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\vafaeene\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\vafaeene\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\vafaeene\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\vafaeene\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}
```

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Comment: read the docs throughly. dont do hit and trial. it ll save you a lot of time. i appriciate what you are trying to make but gain knowlege first. => https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: i have no intention to offend you brother but you should learn to initalise Firebase Admin SDK. that's what that link contains.

Comment: @example There is no try and error here. Did you even read what you suggest? And Yes I read it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: let me show you some code that i have of firebase admin sdk that i have currently deployed to firebase functions

Comment: @example It was not taken as offend. It was a suggestion to me and I appreciate. The link that you sent doesn't give any hint what I should do with the files or how I can connect these files to my firebase. I tried `firebase init` and added the functions, but I thing I can't figure it out. These are the files of a server already inside a folder in my pc. I have to link them to the firebase.

Comment: wait i m writing answer

Comment: ok i can see that the package.json was build in a linux system and your are probabily using windows. so i m adding an updated `package.json ` updaete yours to mine if you are on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this code brother 
i m using it in my firebase functions
the code lies in index.ts

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const serviceAccount = require('../common/serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<project-id>.appspot.com"
});
```

following is my directory structure

```
functions
      ├── common
      |     └── serviceAccountKey.json
      └── src
           └── index.ts
```

hope this help. ask if you face problem ;)

[UPDATE]

there is no problem with your `firebase.json`. actually it is looking for the right folder. put the package.json in right place, where it is kept is wrong. it should be kept outside the server folder. where the src folder lies so this should be the updated directory structure :

```
   myProjectFolder
      ├──server
      |    ├── common
      |    |     └── serviceAccountKey.json
      |    ├── src
      |    |    └── index.ts
      |    └──package.json, tsconfig.json and other files
      └── firebase.json
```

update your folder structure to this and git the command `firebase deploy --only functions` from `myProjectFolder`

package.json for windows [EDIT]

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint", // observe here $RESOURCE_DIR has been replaced with %RESOURCE_DIR%
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build" // same change as above
    ],
    "source": "server"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [ ]
  }
}
```

try this and comment back

Comment: I updated the answer with the error that I get. It seems there is an issue with the server (server is not defined...). I don't understand this language as I am newbie to npm. And interestingly, this is the official tutorial by google and it seems no one cares to correct it in the git.

Comment: i dont have privlege but i m helping you dont worry. this is not a big problem. look at the updated answer

Comment: thanks. But I don't have "lib" folder either. There are two folders: src and test. I will try now.

Comment: I did test it. The same issue. this time it created another folder called "lib" which is empty.  It is looking for package.json file inside the source folder. OMG what stupid I am. I have to change it to "src". I already have this folder inside the project.

Comment: that ll be created once your `ts` code gets compiled into `js` code dont worry just do it

Comment: wait i got it this time i told you wrong way i m updating answer wait

Comment: I think it should be the solution. let me try

Comment: There is the same error. I will update my post with error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211997/discussion-between-namikaze-minato-and-example).

Comment: reply in the chat i m online

Comment: It worked! thanks. Except I got one error: `! functions[subscription_status(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "09876545d31e0b108dbd2e516c6ed4a3e6a63d79698e350f0e5c471b7b263cd0", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"}, {"status": "HIT", "hash": "09876545d31e0b108dbd2e516c6ed4a3e6a63d79698e350f0e5c471b7b263cd0", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}`

Comment: give the command => `firebase logout && firebase login && firebase deploy`. it might be some cache problem. once you logout and login firebase cli cleans the caches

Comment: Can you take a look into this q as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61377135/does-play-console-show-the-revenue-for-test-subscriptions-and-test-in-app-purcha