# Does play console show the revenue for test subscriptions and test in-app purchases?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I have published an android app in internal test track to test user subscriptions. I also linked my Firebase project to it to keep control of the subscriptions. There is also a tester with licence to test the subscription with a fake card. The tester can successfully subscribe for monthly payments and the google play app in the phone confirms the subscription. The user info is also shown inside the Firebase project after subscription. But the revenue is still showing nothing in play console (as if no one purchased anything). "New user acquired" is also showing nothing in play console. How is it possible? Because Firebase is showing the new user info. I also get Realtime user login info in google Analytics. But the revenue is still 0 in analytics.
I also noticed play console shows nothing about my app (no revenue, no reviews, no subscribers, etc.)

[image]

Does play console just show the revenue for actual purchases?

I did not add Firebase analytics to the gradle dependencies (`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'`) But I added all the other dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
```

I am a bit confused. If you have any experience please share them. If you need any other info or code, please let me know.

Comment: i havent worked with them. so i cant say anything about play in app purchases. you can take support from console team. you can seen a support icon in top drawer right corner

Comment: That dashboard is only for production information. However you have a way to see the purchased subscription items where test subscriptions appears. I think you should be able to see them somewhere near financial reports. I don't have access to a merchant account right now so i cannot tell you exactly

Comment: @Lenin I can see them in "order management" section which is for all apps. All of them are refunded and total is $0. But I can see each purchase with an order ID. Still I can't find any subscribers. Is it supposed to be so? Even the subscribers are not shown in dashboard?

Comment: It seems revenue and subscriptions are updated every 15th of the next month...

Comment: I add the same problem. You must wait a bit I think. It takes few time before it appears.

Comment: @Pozinux Do you have experience with subscription purchases (with backend server)? There are multiple crashes even though I set everything up. I am following their link here: https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples If so, we can try together.

Comment: @NamikazeMinato, Unfortunetly I don't have a big experience of setting up billing. I just set up in app purchases for one item (not subscriptions) in my app without a server backend. The simplest case in fact. If it can help, I used the following libary https://github.com/serso/android-checkout
Sorry not to be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks anyway @Pozinux I think I will upload a full tutorial finally. Google play tutorial for  backend server implementation can be a bit tricky (for the ones like me with first experience of in-app purchases)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Google Play console shows revenue for actual purchases. It does not show revenue for test purchases.